# How to include scope parameters in Fb login button

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have been trying to add scope parameters using the below code.

When i add scope the button is not rendered. If i remove the scope then the button is rendered.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" ></div>


<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" scope="email,username" ></div>
```

fb login also makes use of javascript in such fashion.

Is there a way i can add the scope directly to the button without calling the scope in js.

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
                 testAPI();
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes,username,publish_stream'});
```

Comment: RTFM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of scope try data-scope:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-scope="email,user_birthday" ></div>
```

Comment: @ Fabio: how do i add extended permissions into it directly like <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-scope="email,username,publish_stream, status_update" ></div> will that work

Comment: Yes, you can add the permissions you want as long as you keep them comma separated with no white spaces, if you haven't noticed you have one between `publish_stream,` and `status_update`

Comment: Oh one thing I noticed `username` it's not  a permission, the username is a field that you get along the basic_info, I've updated the answer and removed it, check more info about permissions here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/